# How to get values from ajax resulted rows?

Tags: jquery, get

So I have a ajax search script using .get() method from mySQL table.

At each row I would have a button,2 text fields and 1 hidden input with value got from ajax result.
How do I get the specific's rows values at the click of the button?

My ajax code:

```
$("#cautare_p").keyup(function(){
    $.get("php/cautare/script_cautare.php","p="+$(this).val(),
        function(rez){
        $(".afisare_cautare").html(rez)
    })
    //end of search script
});
```

Php code:

```
echo "<table width='100%' border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'>
    <td>Categorie</td>
    <td>Produs</td>
    <td>Cantitate</td>
    <td>Discount</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>";

while(mysql fetch asocc code here){
$rr.="<tr><form>
         <td><span class='link'><a href='acasa.php?produse=lista&brand=$categId'>$numeCateg</a></span></td>
         <td><span class='link'><a href='acasa.php?produse=vizualizare&prodid=$prodId'>$numeProd</a></span>
         <br><span style='font-size:14px;'>U.M.:$um Stoc:$stoc Pret fara T.V.A.:$pretftva Pret cu T.V.A.:$pretctva</span>
         <input type='hidden' id='hiddenID' value='$prodId'>
         </td>
         <td><input type='text' id='text1' value='0'></td>
         <td><input type='text' id='text2' value='0'></td>
         <td>
         <input type='button' id='buton' value='Get'></td>
         </form>
         </tr>";
}
echo " $rr </table>";
```

And resulted ajax code would be something like this:

```
$("#cautare_p").keyup(function(){
    $.get("php/cautare/script_cautare.php","p="+$(this).val(),
        function(rez){
        $(".afisare_cautare").html(rez),
    $("#buton").click(function(){
       $.get("php/cautare/insertInDb.php","h="+$("#hiddenID").val()+"&t1="+$("#tex1").val()+
       "&t2="+$("#hiddenID").val());
      });
    })
    //end of search script
});
```

Solved:

```
$(".afisare_cautare table").find("tr").click(function(){
                var prodid=$(this).closest("tr").find("input:hidden:eq(0)").val();
                var cant=$(this).closest("tr").find("input:text:eq(0)").val();
                var discount=$(this).closest("tr").find("input:text:eq(1)").val();
                $("#test").text("ProdId: "+prodid+" Cantitate: "+cant+" Discount: "+discount);
            });
```

Comment: If you want to get specific row, you possibly need to find the row by some way. It could easily be done in SQL

Comment: what have you done till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to access the `tr` (the super parent) of the `button` you're clicking on like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "input.get-data", function () {
   alert($(this).closest("tr").html());
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/n7DQH/

If you want to get the value of the text boxes from where u click,

```
//to get the value of the text boxes from where you click,
$(document).on("click", "input.get-data", function () {
    //first text box
    alert($(this).closest("tr").find("input:text:eq(0)").val());
    //second text box
    alert($(this).closest("tr").find("input:text:eq(1)").val());
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/n7DQH/1/

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? if u keep it clear then we could help u..you needed to get the value of the row yes? then why isnt this **working**?

Comment: strangely I made it work, ill come back and tell if I worked the way I want it to

Comment: Thank you it works great I was trying to figure it out since morning(11 AM,now its 5PM); It didn't worked the way you set the event but it work my way tough all the credits go to you I will post the solved version above

Comment: Appearently I have a issue instead of issueing the script on click of the button it does it on click of the table row.But $(".afisare_cautare table button") doesn't work,neither does $(".afisare_cautare table :button")

Answer (score 0):

You can create an outer div, assigning it a unique id. Populate all the inner data using javascript in ajax callback method dynamically.

Using this approach you can refer any data on the page.

Comment: You mean making a div on each row or the entire table?

Comment: yes exactly, in that way you will be able to refer every row.

Comment: but how would the script would know which row's button I pressed?

Comment: place an id in each row whose database record is that.

Comment: thank you but i managed to solve it using passionateCoder's answer